# Am facing the return type error in the data provider class

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

Can someone please find the issue in the following code? Am facing the return type error in the data provider class.

This is the issue am facing when executing this code,

```
"Data Provider public java.lang.Object[][] testCases.TestCases.loginData() must return either Object[][] or Iterator&lt;Object&gt;[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;"
```

Below is the Test Case Class that contains data provider class and test cases,

```
  package testCases;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import dataProvider.DataInputProvider;
import loginPage.CreateNewProjectPage;
import loginPage.LoginPage;
import testBase.TestBase;


public class TestCases extends TestBase
{
    TestBase browser = new TestBase();
    LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
    DataInputProvider datainput = new DataInputProvider();

    @DataProvider(name="test1")
    public Object[][] loginData() 
    {
        Object[][] arrayObject = DataInputProvider.datasheet();
        return arrayObject;
    } 

    @Test(dataProvider="test1")
    public void createnewprojtc(String cellvalue1,String cellvalue2)
    {
        browser.initialization(cellvalue1);
        browser.environment(cellvalue2);
        login.username();
        login.password();
        login.loginbtn();
        }
}
```

Below is the data provider Class that contains data provider method,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import testBase.TestBase;

public class DataInputProvider extends TestBase
{

    public static Object[][] datasheet() 
{

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Raja\\testgit\\ProjectCreation\\DataInputprovider\\Datafetch.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int columnCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount-1][columnCount];

        for (int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++) {
            try {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                    try {
                        String cellValue = null ;
                        try {
                            cellValue = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        data[i][j] = cellValue;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        fis.close();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Object[][] data = null;
    return data;
    }

}
```

Below is the login page Class which contains the username, password and login button methods,

```
 package loginPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import testBase.TestBase;

public class LoginPage extends TestBase
{

    public LoginPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using = "//input[@id='txtUsername']")
    WebElement username;

    public LoginPage username()
    {
        username.sendKeys("raja.kulandairaju");
        return this;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using= "//span[@id='spnPassword']")
    WebElement password;
    public LoginPage password()
    {
        password.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("Password"));
        return this;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using = "Button1")
    WebElement loginbtn;
    public CreateNewProjectPage loginbtn()
    {

        loginbtn.click();
        return new CreateNewProjectPage();
    }
}
```

Below is the Base Class which contains browser initialization method and environment method,

```
package testBase;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestBase
{

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop;

    public TestBase()
    {
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Raja\\testgit"
                + "\\ProjectCreation\\src\\main\\java\\config\\config.properties");
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(ip);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("File not found exception");
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void initialization(String browser)
    {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium Workspace\\ProjectCreation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium Workspace\\ProjectCreation\\drivers\\geckodriver_64bit.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } 

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    public void environment(String env)
    {
        if(env.equalsIgnoreCase("QA"))
        {
        driver.get("environment");
        }
        if(env.equalsIgnoreCase("Dev"))
        {
        driver.get("environment");
        }
     }       
}
```

Am using dataprovider in the Testng framework.

Comment: Please read why a [Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: `datasheet` always returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

`Object[][] data = null;` condition needs to be removed from the datasheet method in DataInputProvider  class. Please check it again after removing the condition